# Jquery - Form doesn't submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to submit my form through Jquery, but the submit part of my code just doesn't work! And I can't see what's wrong with it.

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION["useridentity"])){
        die(header("Location:index.php"));
    }
    include("actions/connect.php");
    $q = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE useridentity = '".$_SESSION["useridentity"]."'";
    $r = mysql_query($q,$con);
    $f = mysql_fetch_array($r);
?>
<div class="absolutedialog" id="login">
    <form class="loginform" id="loginform" name="loginform" method="POST" action="actions/login.php">
        <div class="label">
            Welcome back, <b><?php echo $f["username"]; ?></b>. Please, type your password to confirm your identity.
        </div>
        <input class="loginformpassword" id="password" type="password" name="pass" maxlength="32"/>
        <div id="passwordfail"></div>
        <input class="regularbutton" id="submit" type="button" value="Submit"/>
        <button class="grayregularbutton" id="gobacktoconsole" type="button">Go back</button>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="blackoverlay"></div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#login').fadeIn(1000);
        $('.blackoverlay').fadeIn(500);

        //Destroy $_SESSION variables and go back to console
        $('#gobacktoconsole').on('click',this, function(e) {
            $(".absolutedialog").fadeOut(500);
            $(".blackoverlay").fadeOut(1000);
            window.setTimeout(  
                function() {  
                    window.location.href="actions/logout.php";
                },
                1000
            );
        });

        //Submit validations
        $('#submit').on('click',this, function(e){

            if($("#password").val() == "")
                $("#passwordfail").html("Please, type your password");
            else{
                $("form#loginform").submit();
                $(".absolutedialog").fadeOut(500);
                $(".blackoverlay").fadeOut(1000);
            }

        });

        //Clear password message error when something is typed in the password input
        $('#password').on('keyup',this, function(e) {
            $("#passwordfail").html("");
        });

        //Prevent default submit on enter, and click #submit button instead in order to execute validations
        $('#loginform').bind("keyup keypress", function(e) {
            var code = e.keyCode || e.which; 
            if(code  == 13){
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#submit").click();

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I tried adding `return false;` below `$("form#loginform").submit();` but doesn't works. Am I missing something? Please, help!

Sorry for the lack of details; if you need me to add some more, please ask.

Comment: Check your browser’s error console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this element:

```
 <input class="regularbutton" id="submit" type="button" value="Submit"/>
```

When you say

```
$("form#loginform").submit();
```

THe brpwser is assuming you're calling **it**, not the submit() method of the form object. Just change the id to something else.

```
 <input class="regularbutton" id="submitButton" type="button" value="Submit"/>
```

The nastiest thing ever! Hope this helps.

Comment: You sir, have my eternal gratitude! That was the problem.

Comment: That wasted more time than I care to admit originally. No one should suffer needlesly because of this. Ever.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen many times problems about form submitting and form validation and I have found that the best way to do it is by using a simple open source jquery plugin such as jquery.validate.js.

This is an example about preventing default submit and posting data successfully to php file.
First you have to get these open source framework and you can use them whenever you want.
Files are three scripts :

```
 <script src="js/jquery.min.js></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> <!-- open source framework twitter bootstrap -->
```

and one css file :

```
<link href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

example of code :

```
<form  method="post" action="php/inscriptionAction2.php" class="form-horizontal" name="register" id="register">
 // code of site inscription : name , email , password , confirmed password ....
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-9">
                   <div class="form-actions">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="newsubmit" id="newsubmit" value="Submit">
                <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset">
                   </div>
           </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

and this is a simple script

```
$(document).ready(function(){

jQuery.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z]+$/i.test(value);
}); 


$('#loginForm').validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            minlength: 2,
            lettersonly:true,
            required: true
        },
        lname: {
            minlength: 2,
            lettersonly:true,
            required: true
        },
        username: {
            lettersonly:true,
            minlength: 2, 
            required: true

        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            remote: {
                url: '/setup/verify_email/',
                cache: false
            }
        },
        password: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5,
            maxlength: 250
        },
        password2: {
            equalTo: '#password'
        },

        gender: {
            required: true
        }
    },

    messages: {

        name: {
            required:"Please enter your first name",
            minlenght:"Your first name must consist of at least {0} characters",
            lettersonly: "Letters only please"
        },
          lname: {
            required:"Please enter your last name",
            minlenght:"Your last name must consist of at least {0} characters",
            lettersonly: "Letters only please"
        },
        username: {
            lettersonly: "Letters only please",
            required: "Please enter a username",
            minlength: "Your username must consist of at least {0} characters"
        },
        email: {
            required:"Please enter your email address",
            email:"Please enter a valid email adress",
            url:"Please enter a valid url",
            cache:""
        },
        password: {
            required: "Please provide a password",
            minlength: "Your password must be at least {0} characters long",
            maxlength: "Your password must be less than {0} characters long"
        },
        password2: {
            equalTo: "Please enter the same passwords"
        },
        postal_code: "Please enter a valid zip code",
        timezones: "Please select a time zone",
        mp: "Please enter a valid mobile number. Only numbers please.",
        gender: "Please select a gender",
        dob: "Please enter a valid Date of Birth in mm/dd/yyyy format."
    },
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
    },
    success: function (label) {
        $(label).closest('form').find('.valid').removeClass("invalid");
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        element.closest('.control-group').find('.help-block').html(error.text());
    }
}).cancelSubmit=true; // to block the submit of this plugin and call submit to php file
```

By using two powerful frameworks, Twitter Bootstrap and jQuery , you can make your work faster and more professional.
For more details you can have a look at their documentation.

Comment: Please, make sure your answer is coherent and grammatically correct before posting.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm kind of new to web development, so all those plugin still scare me off a little. Will try out!

Comment: Caolan Evans , i will try to correct my english grammar :)

Comment: McSullivan D'Ander  i wish the best for you .

Answer (score 0):

First you should import jquery

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

second change the id value of the button to anything else and will work, you may need to set timeout before submitting in order to delay the submit after the fadeout effect

Comment: Ok this was only in case you did not, hope you have read my second notice, change the button's id